# Return value from distributed numbers VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a solution in VBA or IF ELSE with VLOOKUP to insert the value that i have distributed before.

My scenario is the next:

i have:

```
code    "total qty" "location 1"    "location 2"    "location 3"    "location 4"
12345       3           1               0               2               0
12346       6           2               2               2               0
12347       3           1               1               1               0
12348       11          5               0               1               5
```

I have another sheet or the same sheet where i scan the code and i need to count the total scanned and distribute to the desire location like:

```
code    location

12345   location 1
12345   location 3
12345   location 3
12346   location 1
12346   location 1
12346   location 2
12346   location 2
12346   location 3
12346   location 3
12347   location 1
12347   location 2
12347   location 3
12348   location 1
12348   location 1
12348   location 1
12348   location 1
12348   location 1
12348   location 3
12348   location 4
12348   location 4
12348   location 4
12348   location 4
12348   location 4
```

Is there a way to do this with VBA Macro Excel ?

Any help and hint is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like this:

In my example data origin is in sheet7 range A1:F5 and destination is sheet8 column A:B, adapt at will

```
Sub distrib()
 Dim Wdest, r As Integer, c As Integer, v
 Dim Rdest As Integer, p As Integer
 Rdest = 1
 v = Sheet7.Range("A1:F5")
 Set Wdest = Sheet8.Range("A:B")
 For r = 2 To UBound(v, 1)
  For c = 3 To UBound(v, 2)
   For p = 1 To v(r, c)
    Wdest(Rdest + p - 1, 1) = v(r, 1)
    Wdest(Rdest + p - 1, 2) = v(1, c)
   Next
   Rdest = Rdest + p - 1
  Next
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is a good starting, but i need to get the result to know where will go on Scan, so on scan this need to have a look to the first sheet, lookup where go and put in the next cell.

Comment: I think you need to explain your self a little better, give an example of the final result, no one understands what you real mean...